# Why did Daenerys do this even after the bells were rung?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In S8E5, we saw that the Lannister forces on the inside gate had surrendered (and so had the city when the bells were rung). Despite this, Daenerys decided to incinerate the city. Why? Was it that the "Targaryen Madness" finally took her, or is she still the old Dany but felt a tremendous urge to avenge?